# Onclick is not a reserved word. So how does javascript know to associate a function called onclick with a click event

Tags: javascript, browser, onclick

I am watching this tutorial video to really understand (as opposed to just use) javascript events. 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOCbA2TYJ0M

At minute 1:29 the author assigns a function to the onclick attribute of an object.

[image]

I know this handles a click event -- but I don't see onclick as a reserved word.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

How does the browser map the .onclick function to the clicking of the mouse? Is there anything fundamental about the javascript language that associates the `onclick` function with the act of clicking a mouse -- or do browsers just associate the click event with the on click function by convention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reserved words are words that have a special meaning in the context of the language. The onclick function has no special meaning to the language javascript, but only has a meaning to the browser, therefore it is not a reserved word.

Think of it this way: if onclick would have been a reserved word it would have been impossible to create an onclick function that would not be a click event handler nor would it be possible to create a variable called onclick.

As you said, the browser associates the click event with the on click function by convention.

Answer (score 1):

As user mrhobo already said onclick `has no special meaning to the language javascript`. I would like to complement information  on the part `[onclick] only has a meaning to the browser`.

In the html 4.01. specification for the [button](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#edef-BUTTON)-element you will find this definition:

```
<!ELEMENT BUTTON - -
     (%flow;)* -(A|%formctrl;|FORM|FIELDSET)
     -- push button -->
<!ATTLIST BUTTON
  %attrs;              -- %coreattrs, %i18n, %events --
  ....
>
```

In the [list of `%events`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/sgml/dtd.html#events) you will find.

```
<!ENTITY % events
 "onclick     %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- a pointer button was clicked --
  ondblclick  %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- a pointer button was double clicked--
  onmousedown %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- a pointer button was pressed down --
  onmouseup   %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- a pointer button was released --
  onmouseover %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- a pointer was moved onto --
  ....
>
```

The part `%events` is defined in chapter [18.2.3 Intrinsic events](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#adef-onclick): `The onclick event occurs when the pointing device button is clicked over an element. This attribute may be used with most elements.`

So to implement html the browser has to provide an `onclick-`attribute for button to comply with the specification.